# Ошибки при установке apk на телефон

Tags: android, apk

При запуске apk на эмуляторах и при запуске apk через usb на телефоне всё работает, но если взять готовую apk(её я беру из папки: app\build\outputs\apk) и закинуть на телефон, после установить, то она выбивает ошибки и не запускается. В чем проблема?

Ошибки следующие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @SviatVolkov а как собственно добавить эти сторонние библиотеки в apk?

Comment: ошибка болжна быть оформленна в виде текста, а не скриншота.

Comment: @pavlofff а в чём разница? На скриншоте всё хорошо видно

Comment: Отключите Instant Run и сбилдите apk без него

Comment: @eugeneek помогло!!!Спасибо тебе большое!

Comment: Разница в том, что скриншоты не индексируются поисковиком и люди с аналогичной ошибкой не смогут найти этот вопрос и возможное решение. Так уж получилось, что данный ресурс существует не для помощи лично вам, а для создания базы переиспользуемых решений и призван помочь многим людям с аналогичной проблемой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При включённом Instant Run дебаг апк файлы не будут работать при обычной установке (не через Android Studio).

Нужно вручную выполнить билд apk:
*Build -> Build APK*.